# How to limit aplication of decorators to properties and methods in typescript

Tags: typescript

The following method decorator makes use of a property in the same class that was annotated:

```
export function Dec() {
    return function(clss: object, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
         if(clss.privateInternalValue.secretValue) {
             // do something to the method
         }
         ...
     ...
}
```

The problem comes when a class that does not declare the property `privateInternalValue` makes the test always fail and raises an error. I can circumvent the problem by testing instead `clss.privateInternalValue?.secretValue`. But again, the test will always get falsy, and then raise *not a single warning*, making obscure the place where the problem is happening;

I want to know if it's possible to enforce a limit to a method decorator based on the class that it's being used on, even for private properties; For example, using the decorator above the following decorator application **must** fail at compilation:

```
class TestClass {
    ... // all values of the class come before, no privateInternalValue was declared

    @Dec() // <-- this must say that it's invalid to decorare a class that does not have *privateInternalValue*
    foo() {
    ...
    }
}
```

I could change `clss: object` in the decorator to `clss: T` and `T` be like `<T extents **something**>`. But the problem with extending from a class with private properties is that does not allow redeclaration of the private ones, neither for protected properties, so the `clss` would never allow it, neither reassignation of the value; Abstract classes are too not a good option, as abstract properties are required to be public;

Is there a way to template a class as a type ?

Comment: Just forget `private` and all other access modifiers. You can't write a constraint in terms of a private member because it doesn't make any sense to do so. `abstract` isn't relevant.

Comment: I do not want to specify the private modifier, I rather leave up to the implementer class to set it, may it be public, private, protected, readonly, etc. I want to define something to 'templetarize' a class;

Comment: Then, when I anotate want to 'access' the property

Comment: OK but non public members are not compatible with such a design.